# HQL - Why delete needs flush to work and not just commit

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql, dao

Why while managing a DB Hibernate needs flush for deleting properly an object instead of commit (as done with selects or inserts)?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't. By default, a flush is done automatically just before the commit.

Comment: Thought about it, but when checking the data stored on the db the rows were not deleted...changed the flush to "ALWAYS" and it worked fine, so must assume the default value is "MANUAL"?

Comment: No. By default, the flush mode is AUTO.